# How to reset variable in Handler

Tags: android, handler

I have a handler and a runnable, Handler has a loop that runs from 0 to 5. when i start the runnable in handler it runs and increment value to 0 to 5. But if i double click or click more than 1 time than it takes the value of temp above 5. How can i reset (0) the value of temp on every click of handler.

```
final Handler deneme = new Handler();
final Runnable post_score = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        Log.i("TAG", Integer.toString(temp));
        temp++;
       }
};


Button tv = (Button )findViewById(R.id.button1);
tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
           temp = 0;
           for(int i=0; i < 5;i++){
               deneme.postDelayed(post_score, i *250);
           }
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your `onClick()` with

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
       deneme.removeCallbacks(post_score);
       temp = 0;
       for(int i=0; i < 5;)
           deneme.postDelayed(post_score, i *250);
       }
  }
```

Comment: Maybe you meant `removeCallbacks`?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    final temp = i;
    deneme.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            Log.i("TAG", Integer.toString(temp));
        }
    }
}
```

It's not a good idea to have that `temp` as a global variables. Global variables are always a bad idea, btw.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

One is to make temp local and the runnable a (non anonymous) class

```
private static class CountRunnable implements Runnable {
    private int temp = 0;

    @Override
    public void run(){
        Log.i("TAG", Integer.toString(temp));
        temp++;
    }
};

tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Runnable countRunnable = new CountRunnable()
        for(int i=0; i < 5;i++){
            deneme.postDelayed(countRunnable, i *250);
        }
    }
});
```